# Angular : Override console.log

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an application in Angular 7 with many components and many methods in each component.

In every method developers have written console.log('some message ')

Now, I want to override this console.log and append class/component name and method name.

Is there any way to override this and append class name with every log message?

Comment: You can try "turbo console log".

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ChakrounAnas.turbo-console-log

Comment: I don't understand the motivation behind this. With source maps you will know the class and even the line of code of the `console.log()` statement, without needing to override anything.

Comment: @JSONDerulo thanks sir. I was not aware of this. I will check this.